# how to find documents with all elements in the array in the document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I want to kno if is possible do a query for retrieve documents like this

Document

```
[
{
...
id:1
tags:['a', 'b', 'c']
...
},
{
...
id:2
tags:['b', 'c']
...
},
{
...
id:3
tags:['d']
...
}
]
```

`findone({tags:{$all:['a', 'b']}})` -> 1 because a and b are only in doc 1
`findone({tags:{$all:['b']}})` -> 1, 2 because b are only in doc 2
`findone({tags:{$all:['a', 'b', 'd']}})` -> nothing, because any document has all tags inside array
`findone({tags:{$all:['d']}})` -> 3 because d are only in doc 3

There are any way of do this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- you can use `$setDifference`
- if empty (setDifference your_array "$tags") => tags has all the elements, and filter is true

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fpTu2wvHvKI)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$eq": [{"$setDifference": [["a", "b", "d"], "$tags"]}, []]}}}])
```